# Update WP option by plugin

Tags: plugins, options, settings-api

I wanted to set value of **WP option** (more specifically - 'admin_email') by using plugin, **its option** (plugin option) and update_option().

I tried using lines like below, but when plugin code contains them - it gets disabled. Any ideas why?

```
$helper = (get_option('plugin-option');
update_option('admin_email', $helper );
```

**EDIT**

```
$helper = get_option('plugin-option');
update_option('admin_email', $helper );
```

Now it's not disabling (due to bracket), but it still doesn't change option value

Comment: What's the return value? That function returns `true`/`false` to indicate if it worked or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option is special in that WordPress has code to intercept your call for security reasons:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option_new_admin_email

> This function intercepts changes to the administrator's email address. It keeps the address from being updated and instead sends the user a confirmation email, with a link to confirm the change.

What you're trying to do could be easily abused, and any change of the administrators email should trigger notices as a basic security measure.

Luckily the documentation for that function also includes an example on how to bypass it

Answer (score -1):

You've got an extra bracket:

```
$helper = (get_option('plugin-option');
```

Needs to be

```
$helper = get_option('plugin-option');
```

Comment: Thx, now it doesn't disable.

But still - doesn't change option's ( 'admin_email') value. Any ideas about that one?

Comment: You're setting `admin_email` to the value of `plugin-option`. Is `plugin-option` even an option in the database? And where are you even running this code?